# calculate atan2 from two raster object in R?

Tags: r, raster

I have to raster object (u and v) [download here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6FFDD661570C7D0A!1089&authkey=!APpo6B9p2h9w0ww&ithint=file%2Cnc) . 
I want to calculate the direction of the velocity based on this equation below

```
u <- brick('D:/uv.nc', varname = 'U')
v <- brick('D:/uv.nc', varname = 'V')
ws <- sqrt(u^2+v^2)
wd <- (180/pi)*(atan2(u,v))
```

Unfortunately, I get an error message below:

```
Error in atan2(y, x) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Then, I refer to [atan2 {raster}](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/atan2) and create a simple raster object below and work fine..

```
r1 <- r2 <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r1[] <- (runif(ncell(r1))-0.5) * 10
r2[] <- (runif(ncell(r1))-0.5) * 10
atan2(r1, r2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raster::atan2` is only implemented for `RasterLayer` objects, not for a `RasterBrick`. I have rectified that in version 2.5-5 (under development on R-Forge). With the current version you need to use a loop:

assuming that `nlayers(u) == nlayers(v)`

```
a <- list()
for (i in 1:nlayers(u)) {
   a[[i]] <- atan2(u[[i]],v[[i]])
}
a <- stack(a)

wd <- (180/pi) * a
```

Comment: Note `wd <- (180/pi) * a` is the direction the wind is blowing *to*. While `wd <- (180/pi) * a + 180` is the direction the wind is blowing *from*, which is more common in meteorological terms.