# how to create vectorplot from velocity dataset?

Tags: r, matlab, raster, levelplot

Related to my previous question about [calculate atan2 from two raster object in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123717/calculate-atan2-from-two-raster-object-in-r). It's possible to create a vector plot where the speed (slope) and direction (aspect) is displayed with a set of arrows (e.g. quiver in Matlab) based on this equation:

for speed : ws <- sqrt(u^2+v^2)

for direction : wd <- (180/pi)*(atan2(u,v))

my dataset sample can be [downloaded here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6FFDD661570C7D0A!1089&authkey=!APpo6B9p2h9w0ww&ithint=file%2Cnc)

```
u <- raster(flname, varname = 'U')
v <- raster(flname, varname = 'V')
uv <- stack(u,v)
```

I used rasterVis package to figure the plot, but the result is not fit.

```
library(rasterVis)
vectorplot(uv)
```

[image: Here the result]

Comment: The file you uploaded seems corrupted. Perhaps something is wrong from my end, not sure. Please verify. The data I see look like the following:
`˜ÃV¼€,a¼Ôw,]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k¼Ë»ù:ƒ½Dî“»oŽŽ=:þ?<þ9j]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k½˜Lù;�ØÍ]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k]^k¾*1:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page of `vectorplot`:

> If ‘isField='dXY'’ ‘object’ must be a Raster* with two layers
>   representing the horizontal and the vertical components,
>   respectively.

Thus, the solution is:

```
vectorplot(uv, isField = 'dXY')
```

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Perpiñán,