# How to interpolate region on vectorplot?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, levelplot

Continue from my previous question ['create vectorplot from velocity dataset'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174721/how-to-create-vectorplot-from-velocity-dataset/36192144#36192144). I still have 2 question how to make the figure look like below:

1) How to make the region interpolation? I have tried used `interpolate = TRUE` but didn't work.
2) How to define the arrow symbol with the same length (It's mean the arrow only show the velocity direction)

Here my data [uv.nc](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6FFDD661570C7D0A!1089&authkey=!APpo6B9p2h9w0ww&ithint=file%2Cnc) and syntax I have written:

```
library (raster)
flname <- 'uv.nc'
u <- raster(flname, varname = 'U')
v <- raster(flname, varname = 'V')
uv <- stack(u,v)
s <- sqrt(u^2 + v^2)

library(rasterVis)
jet <- colorRampPalette(c('#00007F', 'blue', '#007FFF', 'cyan','#7FFF7F', 'yellow', '#FF7F00', 'red', '#7F0000'))
range = seq(0, 0.5, 0.05)
vectorplot(uv, isField = 'dXY', interpolate = TRUE, col.regions = jet, region=s, length=0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post and make it a full example - ready to copy, paste and run in the R environment (including `library` calls, `download,file` etc.). I guess not many people feel like putting together puzzle pieces here to reconstruct your figure.

Comment: Of course, here I already complete my code...based on my code the result little bit different with this figure (above)

Answer (score 2):

(First question) The `interpolate` argument needs the `panel.levelplot.raster` function to be called by `levelplot` (used internally by vectorplot to render the background). However, this does not work directly with the current version of `rasterVis`. You can try this trick:

```
levelplot(s, 
          panel = panel.levelplot.raster, 
          interpolate = TRUE,
          margin = FALSE) + 
vectorplot(uv, isField = 'dXY', region = FALSE)
```

(Second question) The length of the arrows is determined by your data, because you are using `dXY = TRUE`. Thus, you should use modify your data to get vectors with the same magnitude.

```
uv0 <- uv / s
vectorplot(uv0, isField = 'dXY', region = s)
```

Comment: Hi @Oscar Perpiñán. For the first question still not produce a figure like above, the `interpolate` command didn't give me a good look region interpolation.

Comment: Then you should increase the spatial resolution of your `Raster` object. You may try the `disaggregate`, `resample`,  or `interpolate` functions provided by the `raster` package.

Comment: The spatial resolution is quite big (1/12 degree ~ 9 km square), I create the figure above on ArcGIS 9.3.